# How to match the routing key with binding pattern for RabbitMQ topic exchange using python regex?

Tags: python, regex, rabbitmq

I am basically working on RabbitMQ. I am writing a python code wherein I am trying to see if the routing key matches with the binding pattern in case of topic exchange. I came across this link- https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html where it says- "However there are two important special cases for binding keys:

```
* (star) can substitute for exactly one word.

# (hash) can substitute for zero or more words.
```

So how do I match the routing key of message with binding pattern of queue? For example routing key of message is "my.routing.key" and the queue is bound to topic exchange with binding pattern - "my.#.*". In general, how do I match these string patterns for topic exchange, preferably I am looking to use python regex.

Comment: could you provide input and desired output examples?

Comment: input  = "my.routing.key"  , pattern = "my.#.*  , output = true,  here # means zero or more words, * means exactly one word.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear enough. you receive random strings and have to say if it matches "my.routing.key"? if so, you don't even need regex. just `string_to_test=="my.routing.key"` and you're done

Comment: No, the input string has to match the pattern (wildcard match)

Comment: my.routing.key  has to match the pattern my.#.*

Comment: that pattern doesn't mean anything in python [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). have a look in the docs, show us what you got and you'll get some help

Comment: guys, he has a wildcard pattern that he wants to be converted into a regex pattern. so he wants a functions converting 'my.#' into 'my.*' that he can use the regex to match. the alternative would be a function that returns whether the input matches the wildcard pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some Java code if that can help you

```java
Pattern toRegex(String pattern) {
    final String word = "[a-z]+";

    // replace duplicate # (this makes things simpler)
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll("#(?:\\.#)+", "#");

    // replace *
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\*", word);

    // replace #

    // lone #
    if ("#".equals(pattern)) return Pattern.compile("(?:" + word + "(?:\\." + word + ")*)?");

    pattern = pattern.replaceFirst("^#\\.", "(?:" + word + "\\.)*");
    pattern = pattern.replaceFirst("\\.#", "(?:\\." + word + ")*");

    // escape dots that aren't escapes already
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\.", "\\\\.");

    return Pattern.compile("^" + pattern + "$");
}
```

maybe someone can translate that into python.

Comment: Can you provide a conversion to C# or VB .NET?

Comment: @DavidP sry regex is for me write only code. don't know who invented that syntax, but i don't even try to understand what's going on when seeing the pattern, even if i wrote them myself. nvm gl to u

Answer (score 3):

This is an almost direct port of the node lib [amqp-match](https://github.com/mateodelnorte/amqp-match):

```
import re

def amqp_match(key: str, pattern: str) -> bool:
    if key == pattern:
        return True
    replaced = pattern.replace(r'*', r'([^.]+)').replace(r'#', r'([^.]+.?)+')
    regex_string = f"^{replaced}$"
    match = re.search(regex_string, key)
    return match is not None
```

Comment: Nice! I found a couple of possible undesirable matches such as `amqp_match('a.b.c.', '*.b.#')` and `amqp_match('a..c', '#.*')` (though they're not problematic if your keys are sensible in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

We're using this pattern to convert RabbitMQ patterns to regexes:

```
from typing import Pattern

def convert(pattern: str) -> Pattern:
    pattern = (
        pattern
        .replace('*', r'([^.]+)')
        .replace('.#', r'(\.[^.]+)*')
        .replace('#.', r'([^.]+\.)*')
    )
    return re.compile(f"^{pattern}$")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this java function:

```
public boolean matchRoutingPatterns(String routingTopic, String routingKey)
{
    // replace duplicates
    routingTopic = routingTopic.replaceAll("#(?:\\.#)+", "#").replaceAll("([#*])\\1{2,}", "$1");
    routingKey   = routingKey.replaceAll("#(?:\\.#)+", "#").replaceAll("([#*])\\1{2,}", "$1");

    String[] routingTopicPath = Strings.splitList( routingTopic.replace('.', ','));
    String[] routingKeyPath   = Strings.splitList( routingKey.replace('.', ','));

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while (i<routingTopicPath.length && j<routingKeyPath.length)
    {
        if ("#".equals(routingTopicPath[i]) || "#".equals(routingKeyPath[j]))
        {
            if (routingTopicPath.length-i > routingKeyPath.length-j)
                { i++; }
            else
            if (routingTopicPath.length-i < routingKeyPath.length-j)
                { j++; }
            else
                { i++; j++; }
        }
        else
        if ("*".equals(routingTopicPath[i]) || "*".equals(routingKeyPath[j]))
        {
            i++; j++;
        }
        else
        if (routingTopicPath[i].equals(routingKeyPath[j]))
        {
            i++; j++;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# and .NET, consider the following for finding whether a RabbitMQ topic exchange binding key matches the pattern or not:

```cs
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class AmqpTopicMatch
{
    // If unbounded patterns is a concern, consider nuget package BitFaster.Caching
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Regex> MemorizedPatterns = new();

    public static bool IsMatch(string pattern, string key)
    {
        var regex = MemorizedPatterns.GetOrAdd(pattern, ConvertTopicPatternToRegex);

        return regex.IsMatch(key);
    }

    private static Regex ConvertTopicPatternToRegex(string pattern)
    {
        string regexPattern;
        if (pattern == "#")
        {
            regexPattern = @"^.+$";
        }
        else
        {
            regexPattern = $"^{Regex.Escape(pattern)}$";
            regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace(@"\*", @"[^.]+");
            regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace(@"\.\#", @"(?:\.[^.]+)*");
            regexPattern = regexPattern.Replace(@"\#\.", @"(?:[^.]+\.)*");
        }

        return new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.NonBacktracking);
    }
}
```

The tests:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class AmqpTopicMatch_Test
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("this.key", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("this.*.key", "this.new.key")]
    [TestCase("this.*", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("*.key", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("*", "this")]
    [TestCase("this.#.key", "this.new.kinda.key")]
    [TestCase("this.#.key", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("#.key", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("#.key", "key")]
    [TestCase("this.#", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("this.#", "this")]
    [TestCase("#", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("#", "this")]
    public void ShouldMatch(string pattern, string key)
    {
        Assert.That(AmqpTopicMatch.IsMatch(pattern, key), Is.True);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("this.key", "this.other.key")]
    [TestCase("this.*.key", "this.new.other.key")]
    [TestCase("this.*.key", "this.key")]
    [TestCase("this.*", "this")]
    [TestCase("*.key", "key")]
    [TestCase("this.#.key", "some.new.kinda.key")]
    [TestCase("#.key", "some.new.kinda.key.value")]
    [TestCase("this.#", "some.key")]
    public void ShouldNotMatch(string pattern, string key)
    {
        Assert.That(AmqpTopicMatch.IsMatch(pattern, key), Is.False);
    }
}
```